# Drawing a line between html div elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I saw this example in w3schools where you set svg line attributes like x1, y1, x2, y2 and a line appears on screen. I am using same method to draw svg line between div elements using javascript and it doesn't seem to work.

I have two circle from which I read there x and y values using boundingClientRect in javascript and setting it on svg line using set attribute. I want line connecting those two circles

Here is my code

```js
const circle1 = document.querySelector('.circle--1');
const circle2 = document.querySelector('.circle--2');

const line1 = document.querySelector('#line-1');

line1.setAttribute('x1', circle1.getBoundingClientRect().x);
line1.setAttribute('y1', circle1.getBoundingClientRect().y);
line1.setAttribute('x2', circle2.getBoundingClientRect().x);
line1.setAttribute('y2', circle2.getBoundingClientRect().y);
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 57rem;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #64b5f6, #1976d2);
  padding: 0 2rem;
}

.graph {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 120rem;
  background-color: grey;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.circle {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
}

.circle--1 {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 5%;
}

.circle--1 {
  left: 10%;
  bottom: 60%;
}

.circle--2 {
  right: 10%;
  bottom: 60%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
    <title>Connect Divs</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="header">
      <div class="graph">
        <div class="circle circle--1">1</div>
        <div class="circle circle--2">2</div>

        <svg>
          <line
            id="line-1"
            style="stroke: rgb(255, 255, 255); stroke-width: 3"
          />
        </svg>
      </div>
    </header>

    <script src="./script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could link the w3schools example if you know it.

Comment: Inspecting your example in dev tools shows that the line actually got proper x/y values set (at least halfways) - but the line itself is not visible, because it is "outside" of your SVG to begin with. You did not specify any width or height for your SVG, and no viewbox either - so it sits at the top of your document with default dimensions of 300 * 150px, and doesn't even reach down as far as where your two circles are. (Add `svg { background:red; }` to your stylesheet, and you will easily see what I mean.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `svg` element has a size, and your line is outside of the that area.

The default setting for an `svg` is:

```
svg:not(:root) {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

so your line won't be visible.

If you add this to your style:

```
svg {
  overflow: visible;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

You will see where your `svg` is located and its dimension, and `overflow: visible;` makes the line visible:

```js
const circle1 = document.querySelector('.circle--1');
const circle2 = document.querySelector('.circle--2');

const line1 = document.querySelector('#line-1');

line1.setAttribute('x1', circle1.getBoundingClientRect().x);
line1.setAttribute('y1', circle1.getBoundingClientRect().y);
line1.setAttribute('x2', circle2.getBoundingClientRect().x);
line1.setAttribute('y2', circle2.getBoundingClientRect().y);
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 57rem;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #64b5f6, #1976d2);
  padding: 0 2rem;
}

.graph {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 120rem;
  background-color: grey;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.circle {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
}

.circle--1 {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 5%;
}

.circle--1 {
  left: 10%;
  bottom: 60%;
}

.circle--2 {
  right: 10%;
  bottom: 60%;
}

svg {
  overflow: visible;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
    <title>Connect Divs</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="header">
      <div class="graph">
        <div class="circle circle--1">1</div>
        <div class="circle circle--2">2</div>

        <svg>
          <line
            id="line-1"
            style="stroke: rgb(255, 255, 255); stroke-width: 3"
          />
        </svg>
      </div>
    </header>

    <script src="./script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But instead of using `overflow: visible;` you should change the size and/or positioning of the `svg`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

```
canvas {
 border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const box1 = { x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 50 };
const box2 = { x: 250, y: 250, width: 100, height: 50 };

let isDraggingBox1 = false;
let isDraggingBox2 = false;

canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
  const mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, e);
  if (isInsideBox(mousePos, box1)) {
    isDraggingBox1 = true;
  } else if (isInsideBox(mousePos, box2)) {
    isDraggingBox2 = true;
  }
});

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  const mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, e);
  if (isDraggingBox1) {
    box1.x = mousePos.x - box1.width / 2;
    box1.y = mousePos.y - box1.height / 2;
    draw();
  } else if (isDraggingBox2) {
    box2.x = mousePos.x - box2.width / 2;
    box2.y = mousePos.y - box2.height / 2;
    draw();
  }
});

canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", (e) => {
  isDraggingBox1 = false;
  isDraggingBox2 = false;
});

function getMousePos(canvas, e) {
  const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  const x = e.clientX - rect.left;
  const y = e.clientY - rect.top;
  return { x, y };
}

function isInsideBox(pos, box) {
  return (
    pos.x >= box.x &&
    pos.x <= box.x + box.width &&
    pos.y >= box.y &&
    pos.y <= box.y + box.height
  );
}

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawLineWithElbow(box1, box2);
  drawBox(box1);
  drawBox(box2);
}

function drawBox(box) {
  ctx.fillStyle = "lightblue";
  ctx.fillRect(box.x, box.y, box.width, box.height);
  ctx.strokeRect(box.x, box.y, box.width, box.height);
}

function drawLineWithElbow(box1, box2) {
  const startCenterX = box1.x + box1.width;
  const startCenterY = box1.y + box1.height / 2;
  const endCenterX = box2.x;
  const endCenterY = box2.y + box2.height / 2;

  let startX, startY, endX, endY;

  if (startCenterX < endCenterX) {
    startX = startCenterX;
    startY = startCenterY;
    endX = endCenterX;
    endY = endCenterY;
  } else {
    startX = box1.x;
    startY = box1.y + box1.height / 2;
    endX = box2.x + box2.width;
    endY = box2.y + box2.height / 2;
  }

  const elbowSize = 10;

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(startX, startY);
  ctx.lineTo(startX + elbowSize, startY);
  ctx.lineTo(startX + elbowSize, endY);
  ctx.lineTo(endX - elbowSize, endY);
  ctx.lineTo(endX, endY - elbowSize);
ctx.lineTo(endX, endY - elbowSize);
ctx.stroke();
}

draw()
```